# Julia: How to efficiently compose `StaticArrays.SMatrix` from multiple sub-matrices

Tags: performance, julia

I really like [`StaticArrays.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl) for the fact that in many cases (e.g. small to medium sized matrices) it can be so much faster when doing matrix algebra.

However, I am frequently struggling to efficiently compose e.g. multiple small `SMatrix` objects into a larger matrix *without allocations*. While my example below yields a block-diagonal matrix, ideally I am looking for a generic way of composing matrices, where the index partitioning might not necessarily have this very structure (even though well-performing solution for block-diagonal matrix composition would probably already fix 90% of my use-cases).

Here is a minimum example of what I am currently doing when composing matrices:

```
using BenchmarkTools, StaticArrays

# this is just a placeholder for an operation with `m`
@inline something_something(m) = m*m

function compose_matrix(mats, index_partitions)
   m_total = sum(mats) do m; first(size(m)) end
   n_total = sum(mats) do m; last(size(m)) end
   M = @MMatrix(zeros(m_total, n_total))

   for (m, (xids, yids)) in zip(mats, index_partitions)
       M[xids, yids] = something_something(m)
   end

   return SMatrix(M)
end

# a tuple (xindex, yindex) of indices, indicating the position of each matrix in the
# composed matrix
index_partitions = ((SVector(1,2), SVector(1,2)),
                    (SVector(3,4), SVector(3,4)))


mats = (@SMatrix(rand(2,2)), @SMatrix(rand(2,2)))

@benchmark(compose_matrix($mats, $index_partitions)) |> display
```

This is already quite good:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  144 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     19.386 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      22.257 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        35.945 ns (21.02% GC)
  maximum time:     34.551 μs (99.82% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     997
```

However, the `MMatrix` allocation is not optimized out (on both Julia 1.2 and 1.3-rc4). I think I have seen cases in which these memory allocations can be eliminated by the compiler, however I fail to see the pattern of things I am allowed to do with the `MMatrix` between instantiation and conversion to the `SMatrix` such that it is lowered to code that does not allocate. Notice that, while this is a "friendly" case (only one allocation), allocations are even worse if `A` and `B` (and therefore the index partitions) don't have the same size.

Is there a reliable way of doing these compositions of `SMatrix` objects without allocations? Do I have to mess around with `@generated` functions to compose the `SMatrix` in one shot (if so, what could this look like)? Or is there another way of doing this in an efficient manner?